# Format a Go string without printing?

Tags: string, go, formatting, string-formatting

Is there a simple way to format a string in Go without printing the string?

I can do:

```
bar := "bar"
fmt.Printf("foo: %s", bar)
```

But I want the formatted string returned rather than printed so I can manipulate it further.

I could also do something like:

```
s := "foo: " + bar
```

But this becomes difficult to read when the format string is complex, and cumbersome when one or many of the parts aren't strings and have to be converted first, like

```
i := 25
s := "foo: " + strconv.Itoa(i)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 696, accepted):

[Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) is what you are looking for.

**Example**

```
fmt.Sprintf("foo: %s", bar)
```

You can also see it in use in the [Errors example](https://tour.golang.org/methods/19) as part of "A Tour of Go."

```
return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s", e.When, e.What)
```

Comment: does letter after % matter? Could it be %y and %q ? or %y and %y

Comment: The letter does matter, it's called a verb, basically it lets Sprintf know what type the variable is so that if it receives 65 and the verb is %d it will print the number 65 but if the verb is %c it will print the character 'A'. See: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing

Comment: Why is it called Sprintf? S for string, f for format? It's odd that print is part of the function name if the function doesn't output to the screen. This has perplexed me for a while...

Comment: @jcollum It performs the function of the C standard library's `sprintf` function (just like `fmt.Fprintf` performs the function of C's `fprintf`), so it is so named because of C. What does the S stand for in the C standard library function `sprintf`? I'm not certain. Probably "string" because the result is output into a string buffer rather than to a file buffer or to stdout.

Comment: Already in C `sprintf` was a stupid name, as nothing is printed.  I don't get why a language, that want's to be an improvement, does implement the old misleading oddities.

Answer (score 267):

#### 1. Simple strings

For "simple" strings (typically what fits into a line) the simplest solution is using [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) and friends ([`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint), [`fmt.Sprintln()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintln)). These are analogous to the functions without the starter `S` letter, but these `Sxxx()` variants return the result as a `string` instead of printing them to the standard output.

For example:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("Hi, my name is %s and I'm %d years old.", "Bob", 23)
```

The variable `s` will be initialized with the value:

```
Hi, my name is Bob and I'm 23 years old.
```

**Tip:** If you just want to concatenate values of different types, you may not automatically need to use `Sprintf()` (which requires a format string) as `Sprint()` does exactly this. See this example:

```
i := 23
s := fmt.Sprint("[age:", i, "]") // s will be "[age:23]"
```

For concatenating only `string`s, you may also use [`strings.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) where you can specify a custom separator `string` (to be placed between the strings to join).

Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Sc9G_SlURH).

#### 2. Complex strings (documents)

If the string you're trying to create is more complex (e.g. a multi-line email message), `fmt.Sprintf()` becomes less readable and less efficient (especially if you have to do this many times).

For this the standard library provides the packages [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/). These packages implement data-driven templates for generating textual output. `html/template` is for generating HTML output safe against code injection. It provides the same interface as package `text/template` and should be used instead of `text/template` whenever the output is HTML.

Using the `template` packages basically requires you to provide a static template in the form of a `string` value (which may be originating from a file in which case you only provide the file name) which may contain static text, and actions which are processed and executed when the engine processes the template and generates the output.

You may provide parameters which are included/substituted in the static template and which may control the output generation process. Typical form of such parameters are `struct`s and `map` values which may be nested.

**Example:**

For example let's say you want to generate email messages that look like this:

```
Hi [name]!

Your account is ready, your user name is: [user-name]

You have the following roles assigned:
[role#1], [role#2], ... [role#n]
```

To generate email message bodies like this, you could use the following static template:

```
const emailTmpl = `Hi {{.Name}}!

Your account is ready, your user name is: {{.UserName}}

You have the following roles assigned:
{{range $i, $r := .Roles}}{{if $i}}, {{end}}{{.}}{{end}}
`
```

And provide data like this for executing it:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{
    "Name":     "Bob",
    "UserName": "bob92",
    "Roles":    []string{"dbteam", "uiteam", "tester"},
}
```

Normally output of templates are written to an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), so if you want the result as a `string`, create and write to a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) (which implements `io.Writer`). Executing the template and getting the result as `string`:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("email").Parse(emailTmpl))
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := t.Execute(buf, data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
s := buf.String()
```

This will result in the expected output:

```
Hi Bob!

Your account is ready, your user name is: bob92

You have the following roles assigned:
dbteam, uiteam, tester
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5KXMHSIUxXv).

Also note that since Go 1.10, a newer, faster, more specialized alternative is available to `bytes.Buffer` which is: [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder). Usage is very similar:

```
builder := &strings.Builder{}
if err := t.Execute(builder, data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
s := builder.String()
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wjJnD1uJlWy).

Note: you may also display the result of a template execution if you provide `os.Stdout` as the target (which also implements `io.Writer`):

```
t := template.Must(template.New("email").Parse(emailTmpl))
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will write the result directly to `os.Stdout`. Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Eo-QiN_QCKJ).

Answer (score 7):

try using `Sprintf()`; it will not print the output but save it for future purpose.
check this out.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    
    address := "NYC"

    fmt.Sprintf("I live in %v", address)

}
```

when you run this code, it will not output anything. But once you assigned the `Sprintf()` to a separate variable, it can be used for future purposes.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    
    address := "NYC"

    fmt.Sprintf("I live in %v", address)

    var city = fmt.Sprintf("lives in %v", address)
    fmt.Println("Michael",city)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`fmt.Sprintf` function returns a string and you can format the string the very same way you would have with `fmt.Printf`

Answer (score 3):

I've created go project for string formatting from template (it allow to format strings in ***C# or Python*** style) **and by performance tests it is fater than fmt.Sprintf**, you could find it here https://github.com/Wissance/stringFormatter

it works in following manner:

```golang
func TestStrFormat(t *testing.T) {
    strFormatResult, err := Format("Hello i am {0}, my age is {1} and i am waiting for {2}, because i am {0}!",
                              "Michael Ushakov (Evillord666)", "34", "\"Great Success\"")
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "Hello i am Michael Ushakov (Evillord666), my age is 34 and i am waiting for \"Great Success\", because i am Michael Ushakov (Evillord666)!", strFormatResult)

    strFormatResult, err = Format("We are wondering if these values would be replaced : {5}, {4}, {0}", "one", "two", "three")
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "We are wondering if these values would be replaced : {5}, {4}, one", strFormatResult)

    strFormatResult, err = Format("No args ... : {0}, {1}, {2}")
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "No args ... : {0}, {1}, {2}", strFormatResult)
}

func TestStrFormatComplex(t *testing.T) {
    strFormatResult, err := FormatComplex("Hello {user} what are you doing here {app} ?", map[string]string{"user":"vpupkin", "app":"mn_console"})
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "Hello vpupkin what are you doing here mn_console ?", strFormatResult)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you need to use Sprintf() for format string.

`func Sprintf(format string, a ...interface{}) string`

Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the resulting string.

`s := fmt.Sprintf("Good Morning, This is %s and I'm living here from last %d years ", "John", 20)`

Your output will be :

> Good Morning, This is John and I'm living here from last 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page specifically looking for a way to format an error string. So if someone needs help with the same, you want to use the `fmt.Errorf()` function.

The method signature is `func Errorf(format string, a ...interface{}) error`.
It returns the formatted string as a value that satisfies the `error` interface.

You can look up more details in the documentation - https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `template.New`, you can just use the `new` builtin with
[template.Template](//pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template):

```
package main

import (
   "strings"
   "text/template"
)

func format(s string, v interface{}) string {
   t, b := new(template.Template), new(strings.Builder)
   template.Must(t.Parse(s)).Execute(b, v)
   return b.String()
}

func main() {
   bar := "bar"
   println(format("foo: {{.}}", bar))
   i := 25
   println(format("foo: {{.}}", i))
}
```