# How to interpolate a number inside a string

Tags: go

**The following code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(say(9))
}

func say(num int)(total string){
return fmt.Sprintf("There are %s reasons to code!", num)
}
```

**Produces the following output**

```
There are %!s(int=9) reasons to code!
```

**My question**

What should I do to interpolate a number inside a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang: format a string without printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to always use the "default" representation of no matter what type, use `%v` as in

```
fmt.Sprintf("There are %v reasons to code!", num)
```

Answer (score 16):

Try `%d` instead of `%s`.  The d stands for decimal.

The appropriate documentation is here:

http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Answer (score 3):

The output is saying exactly what is happening and what you need to know!
As you are trying to use a **%s** **verb** which is meant to strings the output says that:
`!s(int=0)`  which means:

> The value is **not** a string, but an **integer**.

Thus, if you want to know what to use instead take a look at the fmt package page https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ at the "integers" table:

```
%b  base 2
%c  the character represented by the corresponding Unicode code point
%d  base 10
%o  base 8
%q  a single-quoted character literal safely escaped with Go syntax.
%x  base 16, with lower-case letters for a-f
%X  base 16, with upper-case letters for A-F
%U  Unicode format: U+1234; same as "U+%04X"
```

So you can use any of this verbs to have the output correctly represented.
Or as previous answers says, you can also use the **%v** verb which means:
 "the value in its default format".