# How to merge multiple strings and int into a single string

Tags: string, go

I am a newbie in Go. I can't find any official docs showing how to merge multiple strings into a new string.

What I'm expecting:

**Input**: `"key:"`, `"value"`, `", key2:"`, `100`

**Output**: `"Key:value, key2:100"`

I want to use `+` to merge strings like in Java and Swift if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang: format a string without printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I like to use fmt's `Sprintf` method for this type of thing. It works like `Printf` in Go or C only it returns a string. Here's an example:

```
output := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s%d", "key:", "value", ", key2:", 100)
```

Go docs for [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)

Comment: the last one is int number. Can I use %d ?

Comment: @RobertYiJiang yea, I'll edit with that in fact. Didn't realize I changed the type of the input there.

Answer (score 26):

You can use strings.Join, which is almost 3x faster than fmt.Sprintf. However it can be less readable.

```
output := strings.Join([]string{"key:", "value", ", key2:", strconv.Itoa(100)}, "")
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/AqiLz3oRVq

**strings.Join vs fmt.Sprintf**

```
BenchmarkFmt-4       2000000           685 ns/op
BenchmarkJoins-4     5000000           244 ns/op
```

**Buffer**

If you need to merge a lot of strings, I'd consider using a buffer rather than those solutions mentioned above.

Comment: Well, if you use strconv.Itoa then you can as well concatenate strings with +

Comment: @ColinPitrat Due to an issue on the go compiler, strings.Join of 2 or 3 elements use +, but above that it creates a byte slice for a more efficient concatenation. If you have more than two elements to concatenate, I would strongly recommend to use strings.Join.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt" 
        "strconv"
    )
    
    func main() {

         
         result:="str1"+"str2"+strconv.Itoa(123)+"str3"+strconv.Itoa(12)
         fmt.Println(result)
         
    }
```

**Using fmt.Sprintf()**

```
var s1="abc"
var s2="def"
var num =100
ans:=fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", s1,num,s2);
fmt.Println(ans);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `text/template`:

```
package main

import (
   "text/template"
   "strings"
)

func format(s string, v interface{}) string {
   t, b := new(template.Template), new(strings.Builder)
   template.Must(t.Parse(s)).Execute(b, v)
   return b.String()
}

func main() {
   s := struct{
      Key string
      Key2 int
   }{"value", 100}
   f := format("key:{{.Key}}, key2:{{.Key2}}", s)
   println(f)
}
```

or `fmt.Sprint`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   s := fmt.Sprint("key:", "value", ", key2:", 100)
   println(s)
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sprint
- https://pkg.go.dev/text/template

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to combine string and integer in Go Lang(Version: go1.18.1 Latest)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const name, age = "John", 26
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%s is %d years old.\n", name, age)
    io.WriteString(os.Stdout, s) // Ignoring error for simplicity.
}
```

Output:

John is 26 years old.

Comment: Reference and document link: [go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf)