# Golang Convert String to io.Writer?

Tags: string, go, writer

Is it possible to convert a `string` to an `io.Writer` type in Golang?

I will be using this string in `fmt.Fprintf()` but I am unable to convert the type.

Comment: Why don't use fmt.Sprintf()?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can't write into a `string`, `string`s in Go are immutable.

The best alternatives are the [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) and since Go 1.10 the faster [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) types: they implement [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) so you can write into them, and you can obtain their content as a `string` with [`Buffer.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.String) and [`Builder.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder.String), or as a byte slice with [`Buffer.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes).

You can also have a `string` as the initial content of the buffer if you create the buffer with [`bytes.NewBufferString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBufferString):

```
s := "Hello"
buf := bytes.NewBufferString(s)
fmt.Fprint(buf, ", World!")
fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1t1WbejN0c)):

```
Hello, World!
```

If you want to append a variable of type `string` (or any value of `string` type), you can simply use [`Buffer.WriteString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteString) (or [`Builder.WriteString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder.WriteString)):

```
s2 := "to be appended"
buf.WriteString(s2)
```

Or:

```
fmt.Fprint(buf, s2)
```

Also note that if you just want to concatenate 2 `string`s, you don't need to create a buffer and use [`fmt.Fprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf), you can simply use the `+` operator to concatenate them:

```
s := "Hello"
s2 := ", World!"

s3 := s + s2  // "Hello, World!"
```

Also see: [Golang: format a string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

It may also be of interest: [What's the difference between ResponseWriter.Write and io.WriteString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863374/whats-the-difference-between-responsewriter-write-and-io-writestring/37872799#37872799)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I could use a variable with a type of string in the function fmt.Fprintf() please. :)

Answer (score 13):

I saw the other answer mention `strings.Builder`, but I didn't see an example. So here you go:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   b := new(strings.Builder)
   fmt.Fprint(b, "south north")
   println(b.String())
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#Builder

Comment: In the case of `strings.Builder`, you can also use `.WriteString(s string)` method on builder instead of passing builder to `fmt.Fprint`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bytes.Buffer` which implements the `Write()` method.

```
import "bytes"

writer := bytes.NewBufferString("your string")
```