# What's the difference between ResponseWriter.Write and io.WriteString?

Tags: string, http, go, slice

I've seen three ways of writing content to HTTP response:

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "blabla.\n")
}
```

And:

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("blabla\n"))
}
```

Also there's:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "blabla")
```

What's the difference between them? Which one is preferred to use?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

#### `io.Writer`

An output stream represents a target to which you can write sequence(s) of bytes. In Go this is captured by the general [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) interface:

```
type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

Everything that has this single `Write()` method can be used as an output, for example a file on your disk ([`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File)), a network connection ([`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn)) or an in-memory buffer ([`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)).

The [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) that is used to configure the HTTP response and send the data to the client is also such an `io.Writer`, the data you want to send (the response body) is assembled by calling (not necessarily just once) `ResponseWriter.Write()` (which is to implement the general `io.Writer`). This is the only guarantee you have about the implementation of the `http.ResponseWriter` interface (regarding sending the body).

#### `WriteString()`

Now on to `WriteString()`. Often we want to write textual data to an `io.Writer`. Yes, we can do that simply by converting the `string` to a `[]byte`, e.g.

```
w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
```

which works as expected. However this is a very frequent operation and so there is a "generally" accepted method for this captured by the [`io.StringWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#StringWriter) interface (available since [Go 1.12](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#io), prior to that it was unexported):

```
type StringWriter interface {
    WriteString(s string) (n int, err error)
}
```

This method gives the possibility to write a `string` value instead of a `[]byte`. So if something (that also implements `io.Writer`) implements this method, you can simply pass `string` values without `[]byte` conversion. *This seems like a minor simplification in code, but it's more than that.* Converting a `string` to `[]byte` has to make a copy of the `string` content (because `string` values are immutable in Go, read more about it here: [golang: []byte(string) vs []byte(*string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470284/golang-bytestring-vs-bytestring/43470344#43470344)), so there is some overhead which becomes noticeable if the `string` is "bigger" and/or you have to do this many times.

Depending on the nature and implementation details of an `io.Writer`, it may be possible to write the content of a `string` without converting it to `[]byte` and thus avoiding the above mentioned overhead.

As an example, if an `io.Writer` is something that writes to an in-memory buffer (`bytes.Buffer` is such an example), it may utilize the builtin [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) function:

> The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a destination slice. **(As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a string to a slice of bytes.)**

The `copy()` may be used to copy the content (bytes) of a `string` into a `[]byte` without converting the `string` to `[]byte`, e.g.:

```
buf := make([]byte, 100)
copy(buf, "Hello")
```

Now there is a "utility" function [`io.WriteString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteString) that writes a `string` into an `io.Writer`. But it does this by first checking if the (dynamic type of the) passed `io.Writer` has a `WriteString()` method, and if so, that will be used (whose implementation is likely more efficient). If the passed `io.Writer` has no such method, then the general *convert-to-byte-slice-and-write-that* method will be used as a "fallback".

You might think that this `WriteString()` will only prevail in case of in-memory buffers, but that is not true. Responses of web requests are also often buffered (using an in-memory buffer), so it may improve performance in case of `http.ResponseWriter` too. And if you look at the implementation of `http.ResponseWriter`: it's the unexported type `http.response` ([`server.go`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go) currently line #308) which does implement `WriteString()` (currently line #1212) so it does imply improvement.

All in all, whenever you write `string` values, recommended to use `io.WriteString()` as it may be more efficient (faster).

#### `fmt.Fprintf()`

You should look at this as a convenient and easy way to add more formatting to the data you want to write, in exchange for being somewhat less performant.

So use [`fmt.Fprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) if you want formatted `string` created in the easy way, e.g.:

```
name := "Bob"
age := 23
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi, my name is %s and I'm %d years old.", name, age)
```

Which will result in the following `string` to be written:

```
Hi, my name is Bob and I'm 23 years old.
```

One thing you must not forget: `fmt.Fprintf()` expects a *format string*, so it will be preprocessed and not written as-is to the output. As a quick example:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "100 %%")
```

You'd expect that `"100 %%"` would be written to the output (with 2 `%` characters), but only one will be sent as in the format string `%` is a special character and `%%` will only result in one `%` in the output.

If you just want to write a `string` using the `fmt` package, use [`fmt.Fprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint) which does not require a format `string`:

```
fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello")
```

Another benefit of using the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package is that you can write values of other types too, not just `string`s, e.g.

```
fmt.Fprint(w, 23, time.Now())
```

(Of course the rules how to convert any value to a `string`–and to series of bytes eventually–is well defined, in the doc of the `fmt` package.)

For "simple" formatted outputs the `fmt` package might be OK. For complex output documents do consider using the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) (for general text) and [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) (whenever the output is HTML).

#### Passing / handing over `http.ResponseWriter`

For completeness, we should mention that often the content you want to send as the web response is generated by "something" that supports "streaming" the result. An example may be a JSON response, which is generated from a struct or map.

In such cases it's often more efficient to pass / hand over your `http.ResponseWriter` which is an `io.Writer` to this *something* if it supports writing the result to an `io.Writer` on-the-fly.

A good example of this is generating JSON responses. Sure, you could marshal an object into JSON with [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), which returns you a byte slice, which you can simply send by calling `ResponseWriter.Write()`.

However, it is more efficient to let the `json` package know that you have an `io.Writer`, and ultimately you want to send the result to that. That way it is unnecessary to first generate the JSON text in a buffer, which you just write into your response and then discard. You can create a new [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) by calling [`json.NewEncoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewEncoder) to which you can pass your `http.ResponseWriter` as an `io.Writer`, and calling [`Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.Encode) after that will directly write the JSON result into your response writer.

One disadvantage here is that if generating the JSON response fails, you might have a partially sent / committed response which you cannot take back. If this is a problem for you, you don't really have a choice other than generating the response in a buffer, and if marshaling succeeds, then you may write the complete response at once.

Comment: So if I'm sending back marshaled JSON, using `write` is enough since it's byte?

Comment: @laike9m It depends how you do the marshaling. First don't forget to properly set response headers (content type). Then you may marshal using [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) and simply `w.Write()` the result, or you may create a new [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) wrapping the `ResponseWriter` as the underlying / target writer. It also depends how you want to handle errors, as marshaling first gives you more options how to proceed, opposed to `json.Encoder` in which case response may already be written when an error is detected.

Comment: I don't quite understand this: `It also depends how you want to handle errors, as marshaling first gives you more options how to proceed, opposed to json.Encoder in which case response may already be written when an error is detected.` Could you explain a bit or give an example?

Comment: @laike9m If you use `json.Marshal()`, it first tries to marshal the value, and returns the result as a `[]byte` and an `error` if marshaling failed. At this point nothing is written to the `ResponseWriter`, so if there was an error, you may even choose to send back an HTML error page (different content type).

Comment: @laike9m If you use `json.Encoder` and you call `Encoder.Encode()`, it tries to write the JSON data to the `ResponseWriter` and returns an `error` if there was one. But at the point when an error is returned, `Encode()` might have already written some partial data to the response (implying headers being committed): you can't "take back" the partially written data and you also can't modify HTTP headers at this point. If you would want to change the response at this time: you're screwed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thx for reply.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from [here(ResponseWriter)](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter), that it is a interface with `Write([]byte) (int, error)` method.

So in `io.WriteString` and `fmt.Fprintf` both are taking [Writer](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) as 1st argument which is also a interface wrapping `Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)` method

```
type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

So when you call io.WriteString(w,"blah") [check here](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteString)

```
func WriteString(w Writer, s string) (n int, err error) {
  if sw, ok := w.(stringWriter); ok {
      return sw.WriteString(s)
  }
  return w.Write([]byte(s))
}
```

or fmt.Fprintf(w, "blabla") [check here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf)

```
func Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
   p := newPrinter()
   p.doPrintf(format, a)
   n, err = w.Write(p.buf)
   p.free()
   return
}
```

you are just calling Write Method indirectly as you are passing `ResponseWriter` variable in both methods.

So just why not call it directly using `w.Write([]byte("blabla\n"))`. I hope you got your answer.

PS: there's also a different way to use that, if you want to send it as JSON response.

```
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(wrapper)
//Encode take interface as an argument. Wrapper can be:
//wrapper := SuccessResponseWrapper{Success:true, Data:data}
```

Comment: Why did you add "\n"  to "blabla" in example with `Write`?