# How to reference a variable in a String like is possible in tests in Golang?

Tags: go

The following works in tests:

```
if actualKey != expectedKey {
    t.Fatalf("Failed. Actual: %q. Expected: %q", actualKey, expectedKey)
}
```

In the main code:

```
m["Keyword "+kw+" found on "+url] = 0
```

, but this fails:

```
m["Keyword %q found on %q", kw, url] = 0
```

As suggested by @JimB [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) could be used. The following works:

```
msg := fmt.Sprintf("Keyword %q found on %q", kw, url)
m[msg] = 0
```

**Questions**

- Is it correct to call this approach `variable referencing`? If false, what is it called?
- Is this the most concise way of implementing it?

Comment: Are you just looking for string formatting? [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)?

Comment: @JimB Thank you. It works. I have updated the questions. Could you post an answer and answer the additional questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing. What is string formatting called? -- "Formatting"? (that's what the `f` on the end of `Fatalf`, `Printf`, `Sprintf` signifies). What do you mean the most concise way to implement it? Are you trying to write your own formatter?

Comment: @JimB No. I do not want to reinvent the wheel. `msg := fmt.Sprintf("Keyword %q found on %q", kw, url)`

Comment: @JimB calling variables in a String is just called String Formatting? "hello" + var is called the same as fmt.Sprintf("hello %q", var)?

Comment: `"hello " + var` only works with 2 strings, hence it's simple concatenation. String formatting "formats" the variables in different ways depending on the verb being used., for example you used `%q`, which adds quotes around strings. That's not really the same as concatenating two strings.

Comment: @JimB I agree with that. I was wondering whether there is a name for the latter. `String concatenation` vs. `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way to do it is by defining a struct type:

```
type Result struct {
    Keyword, URL string
}
```

and use it like this:

```
m := make(map[Result]int)
m[{"keyword1", "url1"}] = 0
```