# How to insert a string inside another string using Go lang

Tags: string, go

Most programming languages have a function that allows us to insert one string into another string. For example, I can take the string Green and the string HI, and perform an operation Green.insert(HI,2) to get the resulatant string GrHIeen. But such a function does not come with the standard GO lang library.

Is there any Golang function which I can use to insert a string inside an string?

For example

```
string = "</table></body></html>"

// I want Following Output

string = "</table><pagebreak /></body></html>"
```

Comment: See [Golang: format a string without printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31742265/1705598)

Comment: Would a template fit better here? https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#example_Template

Comment: If you're handling HTML, though, you should consider using a [DOM](https://godoc.org/honnef.co/go/js/dom) so that way the opening/closing tags, attributes, etc. are all _automatically_ correct.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can simply use slice operations on the string:

package main

```
func main() {
    p := "green"
    index := 2
    q := p[:index] + "HI" + p[index:]
    fmt.Println(p, q)
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/01phuBKuBB

Comment: it work for simple string.what about array of string ? my input is array of string.

Comment: You can just loop over the array doing above modification in the loop body.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn the first string into a template for Sprintf. It would look like this:

```
p := "</table>%s</body></html>"
out := fmt.Sprintf(p,"<pagebreak />")
```

Working code here: https://play.golang.org/p/AInfyQwpy2

Answer (score 0):

I had used `rune` and `bytes.Buffer` to insert `<\b>` bold tags at between two indexes and build a result string as below.

```
for j:=0; j< len(resultstrIntervals);j++{

        startIndex:= resultstrIntervals[j].Start
        endIndex:= resultstrIntervals[j].End

        for i <= endIndex && i <= len(s) {

            if i == startIndex{
                buffer.WriteRune('<')
                buffer.WriteRune('b')
                buffer.WriteRune('>')


            }else if i == endIndex{

                buffer.WriteRune('<')
                buffer.WriteRune('/')
                buffer.WriteRune('b')
                buffer.WriteRune('>')

            }
            if i < len(strArr){
                buffer.WriteRune(strArr[i])
            }
            i++

        }

    }
    fmt.Print(buffer.String())
```

[example](https://github.com/amoghantarkar/GoProject/blob/master/AddBoldToString.go)