# String and integer concatenation issues golang

Tags: go

I am trying to write a port scanner in Go, i am facing few problems since i am new to this. Below is the code i have written till now.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    callme()

}

func callme() {

    var status string
    getip := os.Args[1]
    getport := 0
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        getport += i

        data := getip + ":" + getport
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Connection error:", err)
            status = "Unreachable"
        } else {

            status = getport + " - " + "Open"
            defer conn.Close()
        }

        fmt.Println(status)

    }
}
```

I take ip from user as a command line arg, and then want to scan all ports on this ip. Since the net.Dial function needs data in a format like "ip:port" i am kinda confused how to concat string and int each time. Can any1 help me achieve this ?

Comment: If you're having trouble converting an integer to a string take a look at Go's package https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/ specifically the Itoa method

Comment: i tried converting int to string, then the numbers changed their values to some special chars its weird

Comment: That sounds like and encoding issue.

Comment: yea any idea how to get rid of that ?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of (regarding your problem): [Golang: format a string without printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is using `strconv.Itoa(getport)` to convert the `int` into a `string`. Another possibility is formatting the string, as in `fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", getip, getport)` or `fmt.Sprintf("%d - Open", getport)`.

Comment: Can you try these and complete the above code, so that when an ip is given it checks for each port and gives response recursively , please thanks