# String with variable inside that can dynamically change

Tags: api, go

I'm trying to setup an API in `golang`, for specific needs, I want to be able to have an environment variable that would contain an URL as string (i.e : "https://**subdomain**.api.com/**version**/query") and I want to be able to modify the bold parts within an API call.

I have no clue on how I could achieve this.

Thanks for your time,

Paul

Comment: Possible duplicate: the answer is in this question: [Golang: format a string without printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Comment: Well not really, I might not be detailed enough, but my goal here would be to build a function that would allow me to build custom URLs easily and in a sane/readable way

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, one which allows the URL to be configured from the environment, then to have the url configured dynamically at runtime, would be to use a template.

You could expect a [template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) from the ENV:

```
apiUrlFromEnv := "https://{{.Subdomin}}.api.com/{{.Version}}/query" // get from env
```

Modified From the docs:

```
type API struct {
    Subdomain string
    Version   string
}
api := API{"testapi", "1.1"}
tmpl, err := template.New("api").Parse(apiUrlFromEnv)
if err != nil { panic(err) }
err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, api) // write to buffer so you can get a string?
if err != nil { panic(err) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `fmt.Sprintf`.

`fmt.Sprintf(format string, a ...interface{}) string`

As you see this function returns a new formatted `string` and this is built-in library. Furthermore you can use indexing to place arguments in a template:

> In Printf, Sprintf, and Fprintf, the default behavior is for each formatting verb to format successive arguments passed in the call. However, the notation [n] immediately before the verb indicates that the nth one-indexed argument is to be formatted instead.

`fmt.Sprintf("%[2]d %[1]d %d[2]\n", 11, 22)`

But if you want to use named variables you should use `text/template` package.