# How to convert uint64 to string

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, strconv

I am trying to print a `string` with a `uint64` but no combination of `strconv` methods that I use is working.

```
log.Println("The amount is: " + strconv.Itoa((charge.Amount)))
```

Gives me:

`cannot use charge.Amount (type uint64) as type int in argument to strconv.Itoa`

How can I print this `string`?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

[`strconv.Itoa()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) expects a value of type `int`, so you have to give it that:

```
log.Println("The amount is: " + strconv.Itoa(int(charge.Amount)))
```

But know that this may lose precision if `int` is 32-bit (while `uint64` is 64), also sign-ness is different. [`strconv.FormatUint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint) would be better as that expects a value of type `uint64`:

```
log.Println("The amount is: " + strconv.FormatUint(charge.Amount, 10))
```

For more options, see this answer: [Golang: format a string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

If your purpose is to just print the value, you don't need to convert it, neither to `int` nor to `string`, use one of these:

```
log.Println("The amount is:", charge.Amount)
log.Printf("The amount is: %d\n", charge.Amount)
```

Answer (score 53):

if you want to convert `int64` to `string`, you can use :

```
strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
```

or

```
strconv.FormatUint
```

Answer (score 12):

If you actually want to keep it in a string you can use one of Sprint functions. For instance:

```
myString := fmt.Sprintf("%v", charge.Amount)
```

Comment: why not just `fmt.Sprint(charge.Amount)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
    var a uint64
    a = 3
    var s string
    s = fmt.Sprint(a)
    fmt.Printf("%s", s)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[log.Printf](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Printf)

```
log.Printf("The amount is: %d\n", charge.Amount)
```

Answer (score -4):

If you came here looking on how to covert string to uint64, this is how its done:

```
newNumber, err := strconv.ParseUint("100", 10, 64)
```