# Setting POST request form data variables

Tags: string, go, http-post, url-encoding

```
A := 123
B := "xyz"
b := bytes.NewBufferString("a=" + A + "&b=" + B)
r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(b)
```

Is there a better way of setting variables `a` and `b` before the `POST` request is sent?

Comment: What do you mean by better?

Comment: @shakabra to avoid string manipulation

Comment: You're not manipulating strings, you just have a string literal. You mean without having to specify values in the encoded form?

Comment: @icza changed my question to show implied string manipulation

Comment: You are looking for https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values and it's Encode method.

Answer (score 3):

Certain characters in form keys and values need to be escaped, such as `&` or `=`. So to avoid those mistakes, best is to use the [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) type.

It maps `string` keys to list of `string` values. So if you have a value other than `string`, you have to convert it to `string` first. Easiest is to use [`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint) or [`strconv.Itoa()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) (for more options see [Golang: format a string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)).

```
vs := url.Values{}
vs.Set("a", fmt.Sprint(123))
vs.Set("b", "xyz")
vs.Set("tricky", "= & =")
b := bytes.NewBufferString(vs.Encode())
```

`url.Values` knows how to escape keys and values properly. The above `vs.Encode()` for example outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kz6n8NrNRG)):

```
a=123&b=xyz&tricky=%3D+%26+%3D
```

**Note:**

As `url.Values` is just a map (with `map[string][]string` as its underlying type), you can also use a simple [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) to create and populate it:

```
vs := url.Values{
    "a":      {strconv.Itoa(123)},
    "b":      {"xyz"},
    "tricky": {"= & ="},
}
b := bytes.NewBufferString(vs.Encode())
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Y4rQ_3PRgT).