# fmt.Sprint() returns incorrect results

Tags: go, printf

I need to create a string with html link inside.

```
fmt.Sprint("<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>", "/myUrl", "link text");
```

Expected result is

```
<a href="/myUrl">link text</a>
```

But real result is

```
<a href="%s">%s</a>/myUrllink text
```

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I have this warning in GoLand

[image]

Comment: you forgot the `f`.

Comment: Related with more details: [Golang: format a string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/golang-format-a-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Comment: Looks like a job for [go vet](https://golang.org/cmd/vet/#hdr-Printf_family). It'll warn you about things like these. Very common :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fmt.Sprint` will print the string as it is. If you want to format the string, you should use `fmt.Sprintf`.

---

The SO community can be very harsh on beginners, if people do not like what you have written or how you worded the question you will get down voted. Don't fool yourself thinking people are here to help, they only care for the reputation.

Luckily in `Go` we have pretty good [docs](https://golang.org/doc/). If you ever think something is not working properly, chances are that a glance at the docs website will be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

#### [func Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)

```
func Sprintf(format string, a ...interface{}) string
```

Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the resulting string.

#### [func Sprint](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint)

```
func Sprint(a ...interface{}) string
```

Sprint formats using the default formats for its operands and returns the resulting string. Spaces are added between operands when neither is a string.

---

Also `fmt` is pretty big and very useful standard package with a good documentation. You can find a lot of different I/O functions [there](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

*Also it is perkily and weird to write "incorrect result" if you hasn't read a documentation.*