# How to save a rendered template instead of printing into os.Stdout?

Tags: string, templates, go, go-templates

I am new to Go. I have been searching Documentation. In the following playground code, it is rendering and printing it on the screen. I want the rendered text to be stored in string so that I can return it from a function.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string //exported field since it begins with a capital letter
}



func main() {
    t := template.New("sammple") //create a new template with some name
    t, _ = t.Parse("hello {{.Name}}!") //parse some content and generate a template, which is an internal representation

    p := Person{Name:"Mary"} //define an instance with required field
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, p) //merge template ‘t’ with content of ‘p’
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-qIGNSfJwEX

How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply render it into an in-memory buffer such as [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) (or [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) added in Go 1.10) whose content you can obtain as a `string` by calling its [`Bytes.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.String) (or [`Builder.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder.String)) method:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := t.Execute(buf, p); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

s := buf.String()
fmt.Println(s)
```

This will again print (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MoPhtZUaCZx)):

```
hello Mary!
```

But this time this is the value of the `s` string variable.

Using `strings.Builder()`, you only need to change this line:

```
buf := &strings.Builder{}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6FdlCtvvAKo).

See related question: [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)