# set %s of hex encoded from byte to variable golang

Tags: go, format

Please excuse my newness to the language. I found this example of encoding to bytes and then it out puts using `fmt.Printf`, but how instead do I store the string representation of this example in a variable?

```
src := []byte("Hello Gopher!")

dst := make([]byte, hex.EncodedLen(len(src)))
hex.Encode(dst, src)

fmt.Printf("%s\n", dst) // output: 48656c6c6f20476f7068657221 (how do I get this output rather in a variable?
```

I want to set `dst` in a variable to be used later in the code instead of printing it out.

---

*EDIT*
The original question was marked as a duplicate to this: [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing)

However, the answers in there seem to only refer to formatting that of a string using `Sprintf` and in this question I am trying to figure out how to format a `hex` which was encoded from `byte` but the example is printed out in `fmt.Printf` using `%s`. But I would like to format to use in a variable which can be reused in the code in later parts. So I dont think this is a duplicate of marked reason, as that deals with formatting a string, not a hex from byte

---

Comment: If your goal is to use %s to create a string variable, then use Sprintf as in the duplicate question:   `s := fmt.Sprintf("%s", dst)`.  You can also use `s := string(dst)`.

Comment: @ThunderCat: "If your goal ..." That wasn't the goal. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "Hello Gopher!"
    fmt.Println(str)
    src := []byte(str)
    fmt.Println(src)
    dst := hex.EncodeToString(src)
    fmt.Println(dst)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qwT_cGpWoYb

Output:

```
Hello Gopher!
[72 101 108 108 111 32 71 111 112 104 101 114 33]
48656c6c6f20476f7068657221
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much. I was looking for what you just posted: `dst := hex.EncodeToString(src)`. Thanks so much! I couldnt find this in any of my searching, so thanks for the reply!