# Get output of template to a variable instead to STDOUT

Tags: go

I am using `templates` with Golang and at some point I use this code:

```
t.Execute(os.Stdout, xxx);
```

This code above outputs the template to the screen (because of `os.Stdout`) but I would like it to be assigned to a variable instead, something like

```
var temp string;
e := t.Execute(temp, xxx);
```

But of course, this code does not work. So how can I do this?

Comment: Try [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder).

Comment: As presented in this answer: [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t.Execute` expects a type that implements `io.Writer` interface. One option is to use Buffer:

```
var tpl bytes.Buffer
if err := t.Execute(&tpl, data); err != nil {
    return err
}

result := tpl.String()
```

Another, more specialized alternative is [strings.Builder](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder), mentioned in the comments:

```
builder := &strings.Builder{}
if err := t.Execute(builder, data); err != nil {
    return err
}
result := builder.String()
```