# Does there exist a Go string template like javascript es6 string template literal?

Tags: javascript, go, templates, ecmascript-6, string-literals

I'm looking for a way to do things like JavaScript ES6 string template literal in Go. For example. **in javascript**

```
let name = 'espeniel';
let test = `Hi ${name}!`
console.log(test);
```

result

**Hi epeniel!**
Isn't there a way to assign variables in a sentence like this even in a Go?

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly the same, but [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) packages in the standard library come very close.

The difference is that you can't use the values of Go variables defined outside of templates simply by their names, you have to pass the values you want to use in templates. But you may pass a map or struct, and you may refer to keys or struct fields (by their names) in the template.

For example:

```
var params = struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}{"espeniel", 21}

t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`Hi {{.Name}}, you are {{.Age}}!`))

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/s1fU_cmkmYY)):

```
Hi espeniel, you are 21!
```

See related: [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Comment: There's also `fmt.Sprintf`, which is more concise but the format string syntax is less friendly.

Answer (score 0):

In GO you can use the fmt.sprintf function, it behave likes C one (printf)

Syntax : `func Sprintf(format string, a ...interface{}) string`

[See Here for the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt)

[Here for an example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fmt-sprintf-function-in-golang-with-examples/)